# What does e.persisted do in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What does e.persisted do?

This is the very first step when React opens the first DOM.

```
window.addEventListener('pageshow', (e) => { // Safari doesn't fire load event when using back button
    if (e.persisted) {
        initApp();
    }
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/1.5/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching#pageshow_event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, it's a boolean(true/false) that lets you know if the current page is being loaded from cache or not.

For example; If your page is loaded from cache, it will return true. Otherwise, it will return false.

You can see the example from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onpageshow_persisted).

Answer (score 1):

The persisted property returns a Boolean value that indicates if the webpage is loaded directly from the server, or if the page is cached, when an onpageshow or onpagehide event occurs.